# Linq extension methods unavailable to the base class

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is something simple, but I am apparently having a "senior moment".  Why in the following code is linq unavailable to the base class.

```
    public class Strings: List<String> {
    public Strings() { }

    public Strings(IList<String> strings) : base(strings) { }

    public Strings Skip2(int i) {
        var x = new List<String>();
        var y = x.Skip(1).ToList();
        var z = this.Skip(1).ToList();
        return new Strings(base.Skip(i).ToList());
        }
    }
```

This code produces a "*Error CS0117 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Skip'*" error for "base.Skip(i)" (no error for x.Skip or this.Skip).  Why are the linq extension methods unavailable using the base keyword.
I'm running c# v6 in vs2015 if it matters.

Comment: `base` is pretty limited. You cannot call extension methods on `base`.

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code file?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Yes that is why x.Skip and this.Skip have no errors.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, is that info buried in the standard somewhere, it didn't show up on searches.  Seems like an odd restriction.

Comment: It is not really buried: [_"The base keyword is used to **access members of the base class** from within a derived class"_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx). Extension methods are not members of the base class. :)